# pt-table-checksum to compare two tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, pt-table-checksum

I'm trying to find a way of comparing two tables in two databases (master and slave), as I have applied some slightly different settings to one, and need to see what affect it has (if any) on the data etc.

Ordinarily I would use `MySQL Utilities dbcompare` which has worked well in the past, but this doesn't seem to have the option for a single table, and `mysqldiff` is too limited.

So I downloaded `percona-toolkit` to my Debian Server (the slave) and am looking at `pt-table-checksum`. But the Page on the Percona website is very little help, instead filled with all manner of options, but seemingly no examples.

I set up a `test` schema, with one table, and diffent data.

So far I have got as far as:

```
pt-table-checksum h=1.2.3.4,P=3306,u=xxxx,p=xxxx, -h1.2.3.5 --databases=test --tables=t1 --no-check-binlog-format
```

(apparently there is some problem with Row Based Replication [?] hence `--no-check-binlog-format`)

But this returned:

```
# A software update is available:
#   * The current version for Percona::Toolkit is 2.2.14.

TS             ERRORS  DIFFS     ROWS  CHUNKS SKIPPED   TIME  TABLE
08-17T09:54:32      0      1        4       1       0   0.291 test.t1
```

Not exactly what I had in mind. Am I missing something, or have I completely misunderstood what `pt-table-checksum` does?

I'm not sure why I didn't get the latest version either. I ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install percona-toolkit`. (as you may have gathered, I'm not really a Linux person)

Comment: What did you expect the tool to return? A list of the differences?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows workstation and have odbc driver to MySQL, then you might try my utility - there is a free edition. Maybe it will help you.
https://selectcompare.com